# Core Data Light weight Migration Issue

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I Have did Light Weight Migration in my App using following Link.
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-migrations--cms-21844

It works fine till I have old App, But When I Uninstalled my existing App and installed again then new added field is not working. It gives Following Error.

> -[Table setColumnName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16e523c0

Comment: light weight migration is not required for clean install.